# Image shifting to left or right when resizing the page

Tags: html, css

I inserted an image in my HTML and styled it with CSS, but when I resize the page, the image just shifts to the left or right. I want it to stay the same position.

```css
.imagee {position:relative}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin:0 auto;
  transform: translate(-345px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="imagee">
<img class="circle" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" align="right" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `flex` to your parent div & remove `transform: translate(-345px, 0px);`

```css
.imagee {position:relative;width:100%;display:flex;justify-content:left;align-items:center;}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagee">
<img class="circle" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" align="right" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, Your expected result can be achieved by implementing absolute positioning.
You certainly now need to define your position from the left to make sure it stays where you placed it!

```css
.imagee {position:relative}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin:0 auto;
  left : 700px;
  position : absolute;
  transform: translate(-345px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="imagee">
<img class="circle" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" align="right" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the transform property in css.

`transform: translate(-345px, 0px);` means your image is going to have an offset of -345px from x-cordinate.

Answer (score 0):

put your image height auto and width is on percentage(%) 
and margin auto

```
.imagee {
  width: 30%; //30% of your screen size
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: translate(-345px, 0px);
margin:auto;
}
```

see reference  https://jsfiddle.net/Nadeem_Shaikh/tgLyr8aq/2/

Comment: if now also you have a problem then add   CSS on class imagee  display: flex;justify-content: center; to make the image center